# how do you split a string embedded in a delimiter in C++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, split, delimiter

I understand how to split a string by a string by a delimiter in C++, but how do you split a string **embedded** in a delimiter, e.g. try and split `”~!hello~! random junk... ~!world~!”` by the string `”~!”` into an array of `[“hello”, “ random junk...”, “world”]`? are there any C++ standard library functions for this or if not any algorithm which could achieve this?

Comment: No, there is no C++ library function or algorithm to do this. You'll just have to implement this simple algorithm yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't your expected output be `["hello", " random junk... ", "world"]`?

Comment: @goodvibration I think OP means that a token is quoted by a given string. It's a quote not a separator.

Comment: @goodvibration, sorry you’re right

Comment: am I missing something? If you know how to split by a delimiter you can apply that and remove the first and last empty entries, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string s,string delimiter){
    vector<string> res;
    s+=delimiter;       //adding delimiter at end of string
    string word;
    int pos = s.find(delimiter);
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        word = s.substr(0, pos);                // The Word that comes before the delimiter
        res.push_back(word);                    // Push the Word to our Final vector
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());   // Delete the Delimiter and repeat till end of String to find all words
        pos = s.find(delimiter);                // Update pos to hold position of next Delimiter in our String 
    }   
    res.push_back(s);                          //push the last word that comes after the delimiter
    return res;
}

int main() {
        string s="~!hello~!random junk... ~!world~!";
        vector<string>words = split(s,"~!");
        int n=words.size();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            std::cout<<words[i]<<std::endl;
        return 0;
 }
```

The above program will find all the **words that occur before, in between and after the delimiter** that you specify. With minor changes to the function, you can make the function suit your need ( like for example if you don't need to find the word that occurs before the first delimiter or last delimiter) .

But for your need, the given function does the **word splitting in the right way** according to the delimiter you provide.

I hope this solves your question !

Comment: A small thing to note - **If you dont want word of length 0**, add the following check condition to the split function above before pushing it to vector - `if(word.length()!=0)`. This will ensure that only **word that are non-empty will get added to the final vector**.